# Finding duplicates among two datatables

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, datatable

I stuck to find duplicates from 2 datatables where the condition is dynamic.

Let's say **TABLEA** and **TABLEB** has same schema

and  comparison columns could be anything.
Columns could be more than one.

how can i build a dynamic condition to remove duplicate from **TABLEA**.

here i tried this query

e.g. i have column name with comma seperated

dynamiccolumnA, dynamiccolumnB, dynamiccolumnC

```
     var matched = from table1 in dt1.AsEnumerable()
           join table2 in dt2.AsEnumerable() on 
         table1.Field<object>(dynamiccolumn) equals table2.Field<object>(dynamiccolumn)
         where table1.Field<object>(dynamiccolumn) != table2.Field<object>(dynamiccolumn)
         select table1;
```

" where table1.Field(dynamiccolumn) != table2.Field(dynamiccolumn)" this statment could be for more than one column.

Could anybody gives me some pointer regarding this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Without any test, I'm pretty sure you can do it with Reflexion: `.Where(x => x.GetType().GetProperty(myColumnName).GetValue(x) != <Something> );`

Comment: But this will throw exception if the column does not exist.

Comment: Surprising, I realize, but you are not the first person in Stack Overflow history to want to join two tables on columns that are known only at run-time. See marked duplicates for some examples, include use of expressions and even a provided library (Dynamic LINQ).

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your problem, you need a query which can be customized without having the source code recompiled. I would suggest you to use  expression trees. They are tough to understand and can bring complexity but its well worth the price.

Take a look at this article 
[Microsoft Article on Expression Trees](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/how-to-use-expression-trees-to-build-dynamic-queries)